# PS 3dpostcard: How to set the rotation point of a 3d postcard layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d

Trying to 3d transform a triangle shape in Photoshop CS5 Extended by making it into a 3d postcard and then using the 3d rotation tools. But the layer seems to be choosing its own arbitrary rotation point. I need to be able to set the rotation point at the bottom of the triangle, and z-rotate it from there. How can I do that? And what rotation point is photoshop choosing exactly, and why?

Comment: To clarify, you're using Photoshops 3d tools, not the  `Transform` tool, correct?

Comment: Haha, yes, exactly.

Comment: Is the card a 3D object? I.e. Was it created in a 3d program and imported into photoshop?

Comment: No, it's a 2d object made into a 3d postcard.